# How to get feature dates according to given date PHP

Tags: php

I want to get date according to my given date for all months.
eg:- bank bill generating.i tried with `DateTime` and `modify` but how i didnt able to get my result.as now it get this kind of result

enter `2017-1-31`
results

```
2017-2-28
2017-3-28
```

but i want to get

```
2017-2-28
    2017-3-31
```

like that.
how can i implement this.can any one help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `date` like -

```
echo date('Y-m-t', strtotime("+1 MONTH", strtotime("2017-1-31")));
```

`t` returns the number of days of the month. In you case it needs some manipulations. It should be like -

```
$date = "2017-1-31";
$day = date('d', strtotime($date));
if(in_array($day, array(29, 30, 31))) { // last days of month
    // Adding 1 month to 31st Jan would produce date of March. So extracting month and year then the date
    $month = date('Y-m', strtotime("+5 DAY", strtotime($date)));
    echo $month . '-' . date('t', strtotime($month));
} else {
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 MONTH", strtotime($date)));
}
```

Comment: it gives the `2017-03-31` not `2017-02-28`

Comment: sorry @sougata still giveing the `2017-03-31`

Comment: i go through the code you given.but if i enter `2017-01-30` but it gives `2017-01-31` and also if i added `2017-1-29` it gives me `2017-03-01`

Comment: @kosala Just increment the day by 5 or something instead of 1.